# How do I combine rows in Pandas without other columns getting deleted?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: This is how neigh looks like]I have the code as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0] 
dfwiki = pd.read_html(str(table))
neigh = dfwiki[0]
delete_row = neigh[neigh["Borough"]=="Not assigned"].index
neigh = neigh.drop(delete_row)
neigh
```

I want to combine the rows of the neighbourhood column that have the same values for postcode, but when I use the following groupby code, the Borough column does not get displayed

```
nbh = neigh.groupby('Postcode')['Neighbourhood'].agg(','.join)
nbh
```

I have tried putting the Borough column in the above line, but then it combines all the similar rows of Borough column, which is undesired.

```
nbh = neigh.groupby('Postcode')['Borough','Neighbourhood'].agg(','.join)
nbh
```

I want the neighbourhood column to be combined, separated by commas, but want the Borough column to look the same, how do I achieve this ??

I want it to look like this:
[image: I want the following output]

Comment: Could you show us what `neigh` looks like please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the first value of `Borough` that occurs for each postcode:

```py
nbh = neigh.groupby('Postcode').agg({'Borough': 'first', 'Neighbourhood': ','.join})
print(nbh.head())
```

```
              Borough                         Neighbourhood
Postcode                                                   
M1B       Scarborough                         Rouge,Malvern
M1C       Scarborough  Highland Creek,Rouge Hill,Port Union
M1E       Scarborough       Guildwood,Morningside,West Hill
M1G       Scarborough                                Woburn
M1H       Scarborough                             Cedarbrae
```

Comment: What if I have multiple columns in the original dataframe, how do I add them. I looked up the syntax of agg() function, but I am unable to make out how to do it.

Comment: @TejasTamkahne Please ask another question for this. It makes searching for questions much easier.